# install rule of python based packages on Debian 9

Tags: matplotlib, installation, debian, python-3.5

In order to install matplotlib in Debian 9 should I issue

> ```
> sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
> ```

or

> ```
> pip3 install matplotlib?
> ```

What is the preferred way? Let me add more detail.

'man pip3' says

> pip  is a Python package installer, recommended for installing Python
>   packages which are not available in the Debian archive.

[matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#linux-notes) confirms this

> To install Matplotlib at the system-level, we recommend that you use
>   your distribution's package manager. This will guarantee that
>   Matplotlib's dependencies will be installed as well.

According to this I shall run apt-get. However, I had a similar case with numpy. 'import numpy' worked after 'pip3 install numpy'.

Using
Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

Comment: I made an experiment. Seems we need first to install debian package
python3-matplotlib, then use pip3 install. Now matplotlib is installed
proper. I'd appreciate any hints explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key quote from `man pip3` is:

> recommended for installing Python packages which are **not available in the Debian archive**.

You can check whether a package is available in the Debian archive by issuing an `apt search` command, eg.

```
apt search matplotlib
```

If your system already has all the necessary dependencies then installing a package with `pip` will work (as you experienced with `pip install numpy`).

If you do not have the necessary dependencies your distribution’s package manager will install them automatically. However, this is not true of `pip`: you would need to resolve any dependency issues manually. In the case of matplotlib, you can find a list of the dependencies you'd need to [install manually here](https://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#dependencies).

Essentially, using your system package manager to install a package takes away the extra work of ensuring you have all the necessary dependencies for that package.

`pip` comes into its own if you desire to work with virtual environments.

Comment: In this instance I started with apt-get, then pip3.
Through the process the both package system guided me until I succeeded.
Would it be similar if I started from pip3 ?

Comment: In what way did the package manager guide you through the process?

Comment: For example pip3 told me:
* Try installing freetype with `apt-get install
* libfreetype6-dev` and pkg-config with `apt-get
* install pkg-config`

Comment: I see now. ```apt``` would automatically install these dependencies,   (```libfreetype6-dev```, ```pkg-config```, etc.)  rather than prompting for you to manually install them (as ```pip3``` did)